# How to traverse through multiple json arrays, perform function on a specific field of it and return the collected result in an api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a city model which its has json response like this

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5eb6c1d24298400b6eb6ca32",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5efc7bb2b413a9524c7f3346",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

What I want to do is based on city id i want to find entities from my entity model which also has an cities field. (so they entities can be filtered on the basis of cities)

In order to make my question clearer if I had only city returned in json response like this

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5eb6c1d24298400b6eb6ca32",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

And I do this, then this works.

```
if (person) {
      const city = await City.find({ _id: person.cities });
      const entity = await Entity.find({ cities: city[0]._id });
      res.send(entity);
    }
```

This works for because here there is only one id returned in json response so [0] works.

But how I do this for multiple cities ids (like in the first json response) and return all of the collective `entity` collectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an array of city id's for which you need to get the entities and apply an `$in` filter in the`Entity` model.

```
const cities = await City.find({ _id: person.cities });
var cityIds = cities.map(city => city._id);
const entities = await Entity.find({ 
                    cities: { 
                       $in : cityIds
                    }
               });
console.log(entities); //logs the array of entities matching the cityIds
```